# Operations no Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the set $\{x : x \in \mathbb Z \ \text {and either} \ x ≤ −2 \ \text {or} \ x ≥ 5 \}$ and let $B$ be the set $\{ −3, −2, −1, 4, 5, 6, 7 \}$.

Find the following :

$A\cup B = \{x : - x ≤ −1 \ \text {and} \ x ≥ 4 \}$

$A \cap B = \{ -2,5,6,7 \}$

$A \Delta B =$ ???

$\mathcal P(A) \cap \{ \{ −3, −2, 1 \}, \{ 4 \}, \{ 6, 7 \}, \{ −5, 6, 9 \} \} =$ ???

Unsure about the last 2, hoping first two ive done correctly

Comment: The first one should read $x \le −1$ **or** $x \ge 4,\;$ your set would be empty.

Comment: For the 1st: use Definition. For the 2nd: use Definition  :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

For the last one, we have that $\mathcal P(A)$ contains all sets of integers whose elements satisfy the *condition* defining $A$.

Thus, e.g $\{ −3,6,7 \} \in \mathcal P(A)$, because $-3 \le -2$ and $6,7 \ge 5$, while $\{ −3,−1, \} \notin \mathcal P(A)$, because $-2 < -1 < 5$.

If we call $C$ the set : $\{ \{ −3,−2,1 \},\{ 4 \},\{ 6,7 \},\{ −5,6,9 \} \}$, we have that the elements of $\mathcal P(A) \cap C$ must be those sets that belongs to both, and thus those elements of $C$ that belongs also to $\mathcal P(A)$ and finally : those elements of $C$ whose members satisfy also the *condition* defining $A$.

We have to check them one-by-one : you can easily see that $1 \notin A$ and thus $\{ −3,−2,1 \} \notin \mathcal P(A)$.

The same for $\{ 4 \}$, because $4 \notin A$, while the last two elements of $C$ are Ok.

In conclusion :

> > $\mathcal P(A) \cap \{ \{ −3,−2,1 \},\{ 4 \},\{ 6,7 \},\{ −5,6,9 \} \} = \{ \{ 6,7 \},\{ −5,6,9 \} \}$.